# What does "need migration" mean for a SQL Server Database Project in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, database-migration, database-project

Sometime opening my solution, the database project is disabled and marked as `need migration` as below snapshot.

I don't know how to deal with that. What should I do to unlock it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your database project is in the old VS 2010 format, as opposed to the new SQL Server Data Tools format.

In that case you'll need to upgrade the project. There should be an upgrade option if you right-click the project in Solution Explorer.

Comment: Or a "reload" button, at least.